# sift implementation matlab

Tags: matlab, sift

I would like to know the answer to the following question regarding SIFT if anyone knows.

Before I start, I refer you to the implementation of David Lowe's paper through this link:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/

The function declaration looks like this:

```
[image, descriptors, locs] = sift(image1);
```

I am not sure about the output parameter `locs`.  Does it return the location of descriptor as the vector `[x y scale orientation]`?

If it gives the location, then `x` and `y` must be a whole numbers, but it gives fractional values.

Answer (score 4):

SIFT uses subpixel accuracy when locating the keypoint. This can be seen in Section 4 [Lowe's 2004 SIFT paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf).

Comment: i mean the location of key point (row and column) should be a whole number.
why is it giving in points.?????
for example value for p(x,y) can be p(1,3).....it cant be p(1.3,3.45)

but this implementation is doing so....WHY???

hope you got what i want to ask.

Comment: Chee, the values for the locations aren't restricted to integers. (1.3, 3.45) is a valid location for a keypoint.